# Unexpected behavior when doing Regex.exec after Regex.test

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I would like to know the reason behind the behavior that I am encountering with Regex.

Here is a reproduction in node REPL.

```
> const BRACKET_ENDING = /[\)\}\]]/g;
undefined
> char = ']'
']'
> BRACKET_ENDING.test(char)
true
> BRACKET_ENDING.exec(char)
null
> BRACKET_ENDING.exec(char)
[ ']', index: 0, input: ']' ]
```

When I do `Regex.exec()` after `Regex.test()`, the result is `null` the first time. When I run `Regex.exec()` again, I have the expected value back. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Regular Expressions have a `lastIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) indicating where to start searching. Every call to `exec` or `test`, it advances this index and the next call will start from there.

Comment: And to the point in this case, because the `test` matches the entire input, there's nothing left for `exec` to match, so the `exec` fails, but also resets `lastIndex`, so when you do the `exec` again, it can now match.

Comment: When `g` flag is absent, the `lastIndex` property remains 0 after each search. In my case, I had to stop using unnecessary `g` flag to make it work.